# Powershell - error using [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory

Tags: powershell

I want to create a .zip file using the contents of a directory using powershell, I've had some success using absolute pathnames however now that I'm trying to switch to relative paths I'm receiving an error when I attempt to create the .zip file.

In the main body of the script, I set the path to the directory which the script resides in using

```
$scrPath = Split-Path $myInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Set-Location $scrPath
```

Then I'm initializing 2 variables to store the relative paths then using those variables as paramaters:

```
$timeStamp = (get-date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")
$files_in = "..\Current\CustomerName\Temp\"
$file_out = "..\Current\CustomerName\" + $timeStamp + ".zip"
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($files_in, $file_out)
```

The $files_in variable works correctly and finds the files I'm after, but the system is doing something odd with the $file_out variable and it's not finding the correct output path.

The error I'm seeing:

> Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could
>   not find a part of the  path
>   'C:\Users\Current\CustomerName\fileName.zip'.

The way I've setup the $file_out variable, I'd expect it to output to C:\Users\My.Username\Desktop\MyProject\Current\CustomerName\fileName.zip but it's omitted the \My.Username\Desktop\MyProject portion of the path - how come?

Comment: `[io.compression.zipFile]::CreateFromDirectory( $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath( $files_in ), $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath( $file_out ))`

Comment: @PetSerAl Shouldn't it be `GetResolvedPSPathFromPSPath($file_out)`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `Resolved` throw exception if path not exist. And I assume, target zip file not exist yet. `CreateFromDirectory` does not handle `PSPath` like `DriveName:\Some\Path`, so you have to convert it to provider path.

Answer (score 0):

When you supply a non-absolute path to a .NET method, it's resolved relative to the working directory of the process (the directory you started from) - a value unaffected by `Set-Location`.

You can resolve it relative to the prompt's current location with `Resolve-Path`:

```
$file_out = Join-Path -Path (Resolve-Path '..\Current\CustomerName\').Path -ChildPath "timestamp.zip"
```